# netconn_send() gives assertion when doing netbuf_new() only once

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow, lwip

I'm playing with UDP within the LwIP stack.

I'm doing something like this after initializing the UDP connection:

```
void SendDataToUDP(uint8* pData, uint8 DataLen)
{
    struct netbuf *myDataBuf = NULL;
    
    myDataBuf = netbuf_new();
    netbuf_alloc(myDataBuf,DataLen);
    
    /*Do something with myDataBuf
    .............................
    ............................*/
    
    netconn_send(conn, DataBuf);
    netbuf_delete(DataBuf);
}

uint8 someArr[]={1,3,2,4,6,5,8,7}

while(1)
{
    SendDataToUDP(&someArr, sizeof(someArr));
}
```

This works fine.
But it is "not nice" to call the *netbuf_new()* and *netbuf_alloc()* each timewithin the while loop. This will fragment the memory. I thought it is enough if we call this only once and the *myDataBuf* will be initialized:

```
STATIC struct netbuf *myDataBuf = NULL;
uint8 netBuffInitialized = FALSE;

void SendDataToUDP(uint8* pData, uint8 DataLen)
{
    if(!netBuffInitialized)
    {
        myDataBuf = netbuf_new();
        netbuf_alloc(myDataBuf,DataLen);
        netBuffInitialized = TRUE;
    }


    /*Do something with myDataBuf
    .............................
    ............................*/
    
    netconn_send(conn, DataBuf); /* Here I get into: "Assertion "p->ref == 1" failed at line 852 in ip4.c"*/
    //netbuf_delete(DataBuf);
}
```

But when doing this I get the mentioned assertion and the program stops by the second call of *SendDataToUDP()*
What I'm doing wrong here?

I have tried it also with a minimal example but same issue:

```
void ExampleUDP(void) 
{
  netconn *conn;
  netbuf *buf;
  char msg[]; 
  ip_addr_t remoteAddr;
  IP4_ADDR(&remoteAddr, 192,168,1,188);
  char* data;
  int idx = 0;

  conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_UDP);
  netconn_connect(conn, &remoteAddr, 7000);

  buf = netbuf_new();
  data = netbuf_alloc(buf,sizeof(msg));

  while(1)
  {
    sprintf(msg,"This is my message with Nmbr.: %d", idx++);
    MEMCPY(data, msg, sizeof(msg));   
    netconn_send(conn, buf); /*Send the message permanently*/
    netbuf_delete(buf);
  }
}
```

it ends up in "udp_send_chksum: invalid pbuf"

Comment: Is `DataLen` exactly the same in every call to `SendDataToUDP`? If not, you will be allocating a buffer with the proper size for the first caller of `SendDataToUDP`. Every call after that will have the same size of buffer.

Comment: You are supposed to use the return value from `netbuf_alloc` and write to that memory. Not directly into `myDataBuf` if I understand it correctly. So, skip the `Do something with myDataBuf` part.

Comment: yes the DataLen is always the same in each call of SendDataToUDP.

Comment: You still have the issue of not using the value returned by `netbuf_alloc`. You shouldn't _"Do something with myDataBuf"_ other than use it as an argument to `netconn_send` etc.

Comment: I have modified the code so in order to use the return value and skipped that part with myDataBuf as suggested but still have the same issue

Comment: I suggest that you make a [mre] of your new code and include that in your question.

Comment: I have added a minimal example